# excel - is it possible to group dates in a column in pivot table?

Tags: pivot-table

I have a table where the columns are months. I want the sum of values grouped by 3 months. I was wondering if this is even possible as the group button is grayed out.

```
January February March ...
999     999      999
999     999      999
999     999      999
```

the output should look like

```
January-March ...
8991
```

Comment: can you show your table?

Comment: where will you use it in mysql or excel?

Comment: @yusufhayırsever excel